# bash variables values from variables

Tags: bash, variables

I have these variables in a file

```
PRODUCT="ABC"

ABC_SERVER_1="server-a.com"
ABC_PORT_1="4045"
ABC_SERVER_2="server-b.com"
ABC_PORT_2="2021"
ABC_SERVER="$ABC_SERVER_1"
ABC_PORT="$ABC_PORT_1"

XYZ_SERVER_1="server-c.com"
XYZ_PORT_1="4046"
XYZ_SERVER_2="server-d.com"
XYZ_PORT_2="2022"
XYZ_SERVER="$XYZ_SERVER_2"
XYZ_PORT="$XYZ_PORT_2"
```

I need bash command line to give me PRODUCT_SERVER and PRODUCT_PORT

So for example if PRODUCT="ABC"  $PRODUCT_SERVER gives me server-a.com and if PRODUCT="XYZ" $PRODUCT_SERVER gives me server-d.com and ports and ...

Answer (score 0):

You're better off doing a redesign of how you work with your variables.  Furthermore, capitals are used in general for environment variables, not for variables in a script.

That being said, here's an ugly hack:

```
name=${PRODUCT}_SERVER
set | sed  -n "s/^$name=//p"
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by

```
  eval 'PRODUCT_SERVER=${PRODUCT}_SERVER'
  eval 'PRODUCT_PORT=${PRODUCT}_PORT'
  eval 'PRODUCT_SERVER_1=${PRODUCT}_SERVER_1'
  eval 'PRODUCT_PORT_1=${PRODUCT}_PORT_1'
  eval 'PRODUCT_SERVER_2=${PRODUCT}_SERVER_2'
  eval 'PRODUCT_PORT_2=${PRODUCT}_PORT_2'

  echo ${!PRODUCT_SERVER}
  echo ${!PRODUCT_PORT}
```

Answer (score 0):

With bash, you can use an [indirect variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

```
server_var="${PRODUCT}_SERVER"
port_var="${PRODUCT}_PORT"
echo "${!server_var}:${!port_var}"
```

```
server-a.com:4045
```

Or with a recent version, a [name reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameters)

```
declare -n server="${PRODUCT}_SERVER" port="${PRODUCT}_PORT"
echo "$server:$port"
```

```
server-a.com:4045
```

---

However, you're better off using associative arrays:

```
declare -A server_1=(
    [ABC]="server-a.com"
    [XYZ]="server-c.com"
)
declare -A port_1=(
    [ABC]="4045"
    [XYZ]="4046"
)
declare -A server_2=(
    [ABC]="server-b.com"
    [XYZ]="server-d.com"
)
declare -A port_2=(
    [ABC]="2021"
    [XYZ]="2022"
)
declare -A server=(
    [ABC]="${server_1[ABC]}"
    [XYZ]="${server_2[XYZ]}"
)
declare -A port=(
    [ABC]="${port_1[ABC]}"
    [XYZ]="${port_2[XYZ]}"
)

product="ABC"
echo "${server[$product]}:${port[$product]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single associative array (honest, I was working on this before @glennjackman posted his!):

```
declare -A table

table[ABC_SERVER_1]="server-a.com"
table[ABC_PORT_1]="4045"
table[ABC_SERVER_2]="server-b.com"
table[ABC_PORT_2]="2021"
table[ABC_SERVER]=${table[ABC_SERVER_1]}
table[ABC_PORT]="${table[ABC_PORT_1]}"

table[XYZ_SERVER_1]="server-c.com"
table[XYZ_PORT_1]="4046"
table[XYZ_SERVER_2]="server-d.com"
table[XYZ_PORT_2]="2022"
table[XYZ_SERVER]="${table[XYZ_SERVER_2]}"
table[XYZ_PORT]="${table[XYZ_PORT_2]}"

product="ABC"
echo "${table[${product}_SERVER]}"

product="XYZ"
echo "${table[${product}_SERVER]}"
```

Gives:

```
server-a.com
server-d.com
```

Note that the keys can be any case you like without a fear of colliding with shell variable names.